# Javascript deep object property access time

Tags: javascript

Here is an example code. Basically two function differs with assigning/not assigning value on `n` to a variable.

```js
let a = { b: { c: { d: { e: { f: { g: { h: { i: { j: { k: { l: { m: { n: 10 } } } } } } } } } } } } };

function notPlain() {
 console.time('notPlain');
 let sum = 0;
 const number = a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h.i.j.k.l.m.n;
 for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
  sum += number;
 }
 console.timeEnd('notPlain');
}

function plain() {
 console.time('plain');
 let sum = 0;
 for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
  sum += a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h.i.j.k.l.m.n;
 }
 console.timeEnd('plain');
}


notPlain();
plain();
```

Can someone explain why `notPlain()` function is faster than `plain()`?

***Edit***
Created `jsperf` benchmark test as suggested.
I guess it's really connected with cashing and javascript engine optimization. Will research more about that. Thanks all!
https://jsperf.com/deep-property

Comment: In my chrome browser's console `plain` takes more than twice the time `notPlain` takes.

Comment: In Firefox, `notPlain` takes 10ms, `plain` takes 880ms.

Comment: Here too with chrome `notPlain: 20.000ms plain: 52.610ms`

Comment: Chrome : `plain: 54.030ms, notPlain: 22.185ms`

Comment: Chrome: `plain = 170.995ms, notPlain = 64.075ms`

Comment: Chrome 61 osx: `notPlain: 20.915ms -- plain: 79.985ms`

Comment: The "code snippet" runs in both equal time, `notPlain` being a little slower.

Comment: I'm also getting the opposite result. I'd recommend running this through a performance testing framework to verify if there is in fact a repeatable speed difference between them. It's also going to vary a lot between JS engines depending on how they handle caching, if they use `const` to hint at caching, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plain uses a lot of references (every inner object needs to be checked each time in case something changed) which it seems to be doing a lot. Not plain uses a single reference to an int, which can be optimized easily.

Answer (score 0):

`notPlain()` is faster than `plain()` because every time through the loop, `plain()` has to evaluate the expression `a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h.i.j.k.l.m.n`, (where `a` is a global variable) whereas `notPlain()` has to evaluate the much simpler expression `number` (a local `const` symbol lookup). Not surprisingly, the latter is a much faster operation.

NOTE: The following answers the original question, which asked why `plain()` was faster than `nonPlain()`.

Your code is producing misleading results because it's a poor way of measuring performance. Benchmarking Javascript is a tricky business. Just-in-time compilers, warm-up, and a lot more factors enter into the timing. Try using a proper performance testing framework instead of a simple test like you're doing. You'll find that `notPlain()` will beat `plain()`.

When I ran your code in node, the first time through, `plain()` clocked in at 10.461 ms and `notPlain()` was at 10.050 ms (so, contrary to your results, `notPlain()` was about 4% faster). The second set of calls to the two methods had `notPlain()` at 7.176 ms and `plain()` at 8.374 ms (so now `notPlain()` was about 14% faster). Unfortunately, repeated runs of this test showed substantial variability in the times (although `notPlain()` consistently outperformed `plain()`), so running in node is not a good test either.

Use something like [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/) to test code like this.

Comment: That should just be a comment, it doesn't explain the performance difference

Comment: @JeremyThille - Well, it did answer the question until the question was inverted. The original question asked why `plain()` was faster than `notPlain()` and I was explaining how that could happen. It doesn't answer the revised question because it's a different question.

Answer (score -1):

Taras, no surprises. It's actually slower (Chrome 61):

- notPlain: 22.6ms
- plain: 60.9ms

"notPlain" accesses "atomic" element in memory. "plain" must traverse the chain of references. Moreover, V8 potentially has to check if no getters, object properties, etc. interfere with corresponding names. Hence it's slower.

Comment: OK, gonna extend my answer.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino, I hope this my explanation looks better now.